Create array out of value method calls in a list
I got a List / ArrayList which has objects of a class B inside. This class got a method that returns an object of class A:
class A
{
    ...
}

class B
{
    ...
    private A aObj;
    public getA()
    {
        return aObj;
    }
}

List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();

Based on this list i now want to create an array of class A:
A[] = listB.toArray(???); Possible? ???

Is there a way to do this easily or do i have to create a method, that iterates over the list and create an array myself?

You mean an array containing the result of calling getA() on each element of listB? In that case it's a simple map operation and then collect to an array.

that is, use the map() (and toArray()) method of Stream: documentation (basic idea/pseudo-code; listB.stream( ).map( b -> b.getA() ).toArray( i -> new A[i] ) [intentionally avoiding method references])

This can be done concisely via the Stream API
List<B> list = ...
A[] array = list.stream().map(B::getA).toArray();

